# Laravel unique field validate not working

Tags: validation, laravel

i have have a field called mac where i store mac address but i need it to be unique to avoid duplicate mac address.

code:

```
return [
            'user_id' => 'required|integer',
            'mac' => array('required|unique:mac', 'regex:/^([0-9A-Z]{2}[-]){5}([0-9A-Z]{1,2})$/'),
        ];
```

error:
Method [validateRequired|unique] does not exist.

structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `devices` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mac` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `devices_mac_unique` (`mac`),
  KEY `devices_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `devices_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: it should be `'mac' => '[required, unique:mac...]'`

Comment: The field under validation must be unique on a given database table.

Comment: Add your table structure here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to define the table the mac address would need to be checked against

```php
return [
    'user_id' => 'required|integer',
    'mac'     => 'required|unique:devices,mac|regex:/^([0-9A-Z]{2}[-]){5}([0-9A-Z]{1,2})$/',
];
```

**Update** -  When updating the record, instead of a create you would extend your rule to.

```php
return [
    'user_id' => 'required|integer',
    'mac'     => 'required|unique:devices,mac,' . $device->id . '|regex:/^([0-9A-Z]{2}[-]){5}([0-9A-Z]{1,2})$/',
];
```